# Crystal Reports 8.5 Stop Horizontal/Virtual Pages

Tags: crystal-reports

Anybody give me an idea to stop the horizontal pages in a cross tab.
It's a total mess up when I export my report to PDF.

Is there any way to do this in printer/page set up? (Without exporting to a separate format)

Comment: can you give more detail.... is there any horizontal page spanning without data?

Comment: @Shiva  All the horizontal pages are with data.I just need to view the data page by page downwards

Comment: May be you need to make columns to rows and rows to columns... use pivot cross tab option... you will get it when you `right click corss tab --> Pivot Cross tab`